# How to prevent users from changing html when buying products via PayPal?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is the javascript code that PayPal provides for their checkout button:

```
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
         return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                      amount: {
                           value: '0.01'  //can't this be changed by clients if it's pulled from the html?
                      }
                }]
         });
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
          // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
          return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
               // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
               alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
          });
    }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

When a user purchases a product, how can I make it so they can't simply edit the price in html? I.e. how should this be validated server side?  And when they finish the purchase, `onApprove` gets ran.  How am I supposed to record the approval information into my database?  I don't want to expose my database credentials with ajax.

Comment: I think you have your answer right there-- you could never safely rely on the pricing information coming from the client.  Most likely instead you'd accept a SKU for the product and the quantity, and then on the server calculate the price to be paid based on the cost for the product as shown in the db and the number of items being purchased.

Comment: *How to prevent users from changing html?* You can't

Comment: `I don't want to expose my database credentials` sounds like a good idea in general :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you are completely correct that the user could change the amount or any other information passed along. You must never trust the client. But in some situations this might not be that much of on issue. For example for a donation you could have a "Donate 1$" button *and* a "Donate 5$" button and the user could change the actual amount but it does not really hurt you if he chooses to donate 3$ or 17$ instead of 1 or 5, you get money and the amount does not matter much.

If you actually want to give the customer something in return, e.g. virtual or physical goods, then you must involve your server in the actual processing / fulfilment of the order: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/ . In that case

- the displayed button talks to your server with the desired order-data, the server can validate the order
- the user is forwarded to paypal with the validated order data and there is no way for the user to change it
- the user fills in his credentials, checks the order, etc. and confirms it (or cancels it)
- paypal redirects back to the server (via. the so-called redirectUrl)
- the server processes the completed transaction, e.g. starts the shipping, sends emails, etc.
- the server forwards the user to a page displaying the completed order or something similar